# Can I view the code of an existing form in my org?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

My task is to develop a modified component (LWC) by analogy with the one that exists.

[image]

Namely, Work Types. Can I view the code of an existing form and the logic of its operation? Or is it not made on LWC? I'm a newbie, maybe this is a stupid question...

Comment: Is this the standard UI, or a custom component to begin with? Have you looked at lightning-record-edit-form to build a form?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you can use the browser's developer tools to view all the code, however, if you are a newbie, you probably want to take a look at what already exists.

For example, as pointed out by sfdcfox, there are built in components with ootb functionalities that allow you to construct forms with minimal effort, such as the
[lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form)

once you have more experience, and require further customizations, you can also refer to the [SLDS blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/overview/) where markup is provided, but, you still need to code the logic behind the ui for it to work.